# Error Decimal to Int, bad round in simple operation C#

Tags: c#, integer, decimal, rounding

In C# i´m creating a simple instruction for get the price after of discount a const percent.
I need show the value like int (round from decimal to int), but then when i show the result, i can see rounds like 47.5 -> 48, but 66.5 to 66... why c# rounds +0.5 for one and -0.5 for the other?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                
public class Program
{
   public static void Main()
  {
    int discount = 5;
    
    Dictionary<string, int> coffee = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    
    coffee.Add("Americano", 50);
    coffee.Add("Latte", 70);
    
    int amount =0;
    decimal percentDiscount = (1- (decimal)(discount)/100);
    foreach(string key in coffee.Keys){
        Console.WriteLine((coffee[key] * percentDiscount));
        amount = Convert.ToInt32((coffee[key] * percentDiscount));
        Console.WriteLine(key+": "+amount);
    }
  }
}
//47.50
//Americano: 48
//66.50
//Latte: 66
```

Comment: Look up _Bankers' Rounding_ also known as _Round to Even_.  If you always round up (when you are halfway between two numbers), then you are biasing upwards.  Rounding to even means you round up half the time, and down half the time (keeping bankers' books balanced nicely)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hover over that method in your IDE, you'll see the following documentation.

> **value**, rounded to the nearest 32-bit signed integer. If **value** is
> halfway between two whole numbers, the even number is returned; that
> is, 4.5 is converted to 4, and 5.5 is converted to 6.

Per the documentation, the number is always rounded to the even number.

If you want to round numbers up, you should use the decimal `Round` method with the [MidpointRounding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=net-5.0#fields) set to `AwayFromZero` before converting the number to an integer.

```
decimal.Round(coffee[key] * percentDiscount, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Comment: There's a concept called "Bankers Rounding" where every number is not rounded to nearest higher value. Rounding it to always closest even number, will make few rounding to closest smaller value as well, and thus balances out,  when large number of rounding computations are involved.

Comment: @GDC Not sure how is that comment relevant to my answer. The question was why is the code behaving the way it does, I answered that one and provided a tool that can be used to round the number in various different ways.

Comment: your answer is totally correct. I was just adding as .Net uses Bankers Rounding internally.